# Why don't I see page view data in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I took the code from the google-analytics website and put it right before the closing body tag like the instructions say to do and changed the xxxxx-x value from the profile page in the code.

I uploaded the new index file and refreshed the page a few times and have yet to get a single hit on it and I'm kind of curious as to why this might be? Any ideas?

Comment: How long did you wait before checking? It's not always instantaneous that it detects the new file.

Also, when you view the page source, you do see the new code right?

Comment: Yes I do. And It's been about 30 minutes.

Comment: Oh wait, you're looking to see the analytics, not that it's detected the analytics code? Google Analytics won't give you realtime analytics data, though they're working towards that.

Comment: Well I'm looking at the dashboard in my profile and its yet to show that there's been a visit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't see analytics data in realtime. Google is working towards that, but there is a lag in showing traffic:

See this Google Help page:
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=450ae99d8e40bfaf&hl=en

"Hi, Google Analytics has a current time lag for standard tracking of about 1-2 hours - so it's almost real-time (do you really want to check your analytics data every 10 minutes?). Switch to the current day in your calender and refer to the hourly reports - for example the Visitors/Visitor Trending/Visits/Graph by Hour report - to verify that."

Comment: Any update on this as we are in May 2013.
I am using google analytics API v3 and likes to know has they did any effort so we can get real time data atleast from api